# Snowflake table not visible from another worksheet

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Why, when I create a table by executing SQL in a Snowflake worksheet is that table not available on the next worksheet?  (Worksheets are running on the same warehouse, same database, same schema.)  Please help.  Snowflake is making my life a misery.

Here's how I created the table...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE "******"."******"."HEALTHY_AVERSION" (
    time TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9),
    traveling int
);

INSERT INTO "******"."******"."HEALTHY_AVERSION"
VALUES ('2017-01-01 01:00:00', 1),
    ('2017-01-01 02:00:00', 1),
    ('2017-01-01 03:00:00', 1),
    ('2017-01-01 04:00:00', 1),
    ('2017-01-01 05:00:00', 1),
    ('2017-01-01 06:00:00', 0),
    ('2017-01-01 07:00:00', 0),
    ('2017-01-01 08:00:00', 0),
    ('2017-01-01 09:00:00', 0),
    ('2017-01-01 10:00:00', 0)
```

This code appears to run just fine and the table is there.  But when I switch to another worksheet I can't see it.

Comment: When you say you cannot see it do you mean in the Schema Browser on the left hand side of the screen?
If so verify that both worksheets re utilizing the same roles in the context menu.  Also the schema browsers on each tab refresh independently.  Try refreshing (refresh icon next to the text 'Find database objects') the schema browser.

Comment: If they we different tabs, I would check if both users have same roles. Here you wrote that they are using same settings, so my guess is first query is using "fully qualified name" and the second not(which may be the case). Are you using in second worksheet `SELECT * FROM  "******"."******"."HEALTHY_AVERSION"` or only `SELECT * FROM "HEALTHY_AVERSION"`

Comment: Another guess is a case sensitivity `SELECT * FROM healthy_aversion` will not work as identifiers `"HEALTHY_AVERSION"`  and `"healthy_aversion"` are considered different

Comment: @DanielZagales  I am using the same role for both worksheets.  I have been using the refresh button, but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I've been careful to use only fully qualified names.

Comment: Seems like it just takes ages for changes to propagate through the system.  Just a guess though.

Comment: By ages I mean hours.

Comment: You must be using different roles on your worksheets. I've not had this issue before and I've just tested it now and it's working fine.

Comment: @Keith No chance it takes hours for a new table to "propagate through the system".  The table will be immediately displayed in the UI...possibly requiring a browser refresh.  Have you tried a `SHOW TABLES` command in both tabs?  I would also recommend making sure you're using the right roles in each tab by explicitly using a `USE ROLE` command, just to be sure.  Also, out of curiosity, what browser are you using?  Chrome or Firefox seem to work best.

Comment: Are you by any chance in open, not committed transaction `SELECT CURRENT_TRANSACTION();` in worksheet where table is created? Maybe autocommit is off.

Comment: does one of your sessions have previously entered "ignore case on double quoted identities" option, and not on the other. I simple test for  that is to create a new tables  as above with no quotes on any of the db/schema/tablename.

Answer (score 0):

This is like an issue with user privileges.  Double check that the second worksheet has the same role as the role found in the worksheet creating the table.  Let me know if they're the same roles and you still don't see the table.